# Filter an array by a condition and changer the key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, object

I have a list of objects in an array like this:

```
[
  {
    "code": "ICh8tTgU",
    "mposMerchantProfileCode": "jjijuhikl",
    "shortLabel": "Pizza 6",
    "description": "Cookies without oil nor butter",
    "priceList": [
      {
        "price": 3.9,
        "currency": "DH",
        "taxes": "11%",
        "formattedPrice": "$"
      },
      {
        "price": 2.9,
        "currency": "YN",
        "taxes": "13%",
        "formattedPrice": "€"
      }
    ],
    "imageFormat": "jpg",
    "isFavorite": false,
    "isSpecial": false,
    "status": "A",
    "statDHate": "2021-01-16T13:11:12.933+0000",
    "imageBase64": "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",
    "qte": 1,
    "isCombo": false
  },
  {
    "code": "9oTjZDRM",
    "mposMerchantProfileCode": "jjijuhikl",
    "shortLabel": "Pizza 5",
    "description": "Cookies without oil nor butter",
    "priceList": [
      {
        "price": 3.9,
        "currency": "DH",
        "taxes": "11%",
        "formattedPrice": "$"
      },
      {
        "price": 2.9,
        "currency": "YN",
        "taxes": "13%",
        "formattedPrice": "€"
      }
    ],
    "imageFormat": "jpg",
    "isFavorite": false,
    "isSpecial": false,
    "status": "A",
    "statDHate": "2021-01-16T13:11:06.843+0000",
    "imageBase64": "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",
    "qte": 1,
    "isCombo": false
  },
  {
    "code": "0GJW16Ql",
    "mposMerchantProfileCode": "jjijuhikl",
    "shortLabel": "Fruit 10",
    "description": "Cookies without oil nor butter",
    "priceList": [
      {
        "price": 3.9,
        "currency": "DH",
        "taxes": "11%",
        "formattedPrice": "$"
      },
      {
        "price": 2.9,
        "currency": "YN",
        "taxes": "13%",
        "formattedPrice": "€"
      }
    ],
    "imageFormat": "jpg",
    "isFavorite": false,
    "isSpecial": false,
    "status": "A",
    "statDHate": "2021-01-16T13:09:59.674+0000",
    "imageBase64": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAAdACEDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwB918NtKsoHnMpijQZLGVqYnhBbe4SCGWYyNF5qp5jA4/Hvz0roNf1ovaogeOO2ceYZA2S4HTafTPOeM9jXlU/ie9uNZdtNeZAMo7IxIIOOM88V5bk5OyPThGyuztVjPnjyL0wI6qRGZhKU653AjBORjAOKfe397aqZILq0aEEH5x95RnPygZ5PHU1wesQXWkXEUsMF2kk2HJVt+7Pt2PboKpvPrgVEeEoHJx0BA9Pr3qPZOWqZtzRWjO7/AOE0P/PkPyorznzbz+7cflRVeyXkRzLsd+dE1XxDqF1Jram3gtsRoscwMjZx09sVan8K6fo+iyCKV7VEPnt53KtgggGuq1DREnInineCcA4kQA8dwc9RXA6vZ3jTyQTXqyjksWiPzfUbqc6ck7LYiFVNXluVdT16zvCLqScS3EnEZXI8pR29MBgT9TWNqHiWMokVsjSSbeZEc9TWlb+GxfmITXjbV+VFCDCgenNdbpPhTTbNVcxmU8fe9zWkaMepM67+yeS/bNY/54/+QzRXv/8AZFh/zw/WituWPYw9rPuf/9k=",
    "qte": 1,
    "isCombo": false
  },
  {
    "code": "R2ABOTYW",
    "label": "Grilled Chicken + Mango Juice",
    "shortLabel": "Lunch 1",
    "priceList": [
      {
        "price": 6.59,
        "currency": "DH"
      },
      {
        "price": 5.19,
        "currency": "YN"
      }
    ],
    "productList": [
      {
        "productCode": "bKSZqaYa"
      },
      {
        "productCode": "MM3FbWRu"
      }
    ],
    "merchantCode": "jjijuhikl",
    "qte": 2,
    "isCombo": true
  }
]
]
```

I can filter and separate this array to two array depending the `isCombo` value

```
var productList = this.props.currentSale.Data.filter(i => i.isCombo === false)
var comboList = this.props.currentSale.Data.filter(i => i.isCombo === true)
```

But what I want is two arrays `productList` and `comboList` with the same values but not the same key names like this:

```
    productList=[
        {
            "code": "EvZfNCUL",
            "unitPrice": 5.0,
            "quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "code": "NcWmRo1K",
            "unitPrice": 5.0,
            "quantity": 1
        }   
    ];
    comboList= [
        {
            "code": "R2ABOTYW",
            "quantity": 2, // before it was "qte": 2,
            "unitPrice": 6.59
        },
    ];
```

Keep only `code, quantity, unitPrice` of each elements (by changing their key names: qte > quantity for example) and delete the other keys

Comment: how do you decide which `unitPrice` to pick in output from multiple available ?

Comment: I have already a chosen currency so I will make a codition on it

Comment: isCombo false should go to productList ? and isCombo true to comboList ?

Comment: yes exactly, I do this with filter method but I don't know how to change their key names and delete the other values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `map` function to define new objects based on your existing ones with new keys, something like this (I named the array `currentSale` for local testing). Also I'm not sure which price you need but you should be able to modify the map to get it.

```js
const currentSale = [
    {
      "code": "ICh8tTgU",
      "mposMerchantProfileCode": "jjijuhikl",
      "shortLabel": "Pizza 6",
      "description": "Cookies without oil nor butter",
      "priceList": [
        {
          "price": 3.9,
          "currency": "DH",
          "taxes": "11%",
          "formattedPrice": "$"
        },
        {
          "price": 2.9,
          "currency": "YN",
          "taxes": "13%",
          "formattedPrice": "€"
        }
      ],
      "imageFormat": "jpg",
      "isFavorite": false,
      "isSpecial": false,
      "status": "A",
      "statDHate": "2021-01-16T13:11:12.933+0000",
      "imageBase64": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAAdACEDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwB918NtKsoHnMpijQZLGVqYnhBbe4SCGWYyNF5qp5jA4/Hvz0roNf1ovaogeOO2ceYZA2S4HTafTPOeM9jXlU/ie9uNZdtNeZAMo7IxIIOOM88V5bk5OyPThGyuztVjPnjyL0wI6qRGZhKU653AjBORjAOKfe397aqZILq0aEEH5x95RnPygZ5PHU1wesQXWkXEUsMF2kk2HJVt+7Pt2PboKpvPrgVEeEoHJx0BA9Pr3qPZOWqZtzRWjO7/AOE0P/PkPyorznzbz+7cflRVeyXkRzLsd+dE1XxDqF1Jram3gtsRoscwMjZx09sVan8K6fo+iyCKV7VEPnt53KtgggGuq1DREnInineCcA4kQA8dwc9RXA6vZ3jTyQTXqyjksWiPzfUbqc6ck7LYiFVNXluVdT16zvCLqScS3EnEZXI8pR29MBgT9TWNqHiWMokVsjSSbeZEc9TWlb+GxfmITXjbV+VFCDCgenNdbpPhTTbNVcxmU8fe9zWkaMepM67+yeS/bNY/54/+QzRXv/8AZFh/zw/WituWPYw9rPuf/9k=",
      "qte": 1,
      "isCombo": false
    },
    {
      "code": "9oTjZDRM",
      "mposMerchantProfileCode": "jjijuhikl",
      "shortLabel": "Pizza 5",
      "description": "Cookies without oil nor butter",
      "priceList": [
        {
          "price": 3.9,
          "currency": "DH",
          "taxes": "11%",
          "formattedPrice": "$"
        },
        {
          "price": 2.9,
          "currency": "YN",
          "taxes": "13%",
          "formattedPrice": "€"
        }
      ],
      "imageFormat": "jpg",
      "isFavorite": false,
      "isSpecial": false,
      "status": "A",
      "statDHate": "2021-01-16T13:11:06.843+0000",
      "imageBase64": "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",
      "qte": 1,
      "isCombo": false
    },
    {
      "code": "0GJW16Ql",
      "mposMerchantProfileCode": "jjijuhikl",
      "shortLabel": "Fruit 10",
      "description": "Cookies without oil nor butter",
      "priceList": [
        {
          "price": 3.9,
          "currency": "DH",
          "taxes": "11%",
          "formattedPrice": "$"
        },
        {
          "price": 2.9,
          "currency": "YN",
          "taxes": "13%",
          "formattedPrice": "€"
        }
      ],
      "imageFormat": "jpg",
      "isFavorite": false,
      "isSpecial": false,
      "status": "A",
      "statDHate": "2021-01-16T13:09:59.674+0000",
      "imageBase64": "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",
      "qte": 1,
      "isCombo": false
    },
    {
      "code": "R2ABOTYW",
      "label": "Grilled Chicken + Mango Juice",
      "shortLabel": "Lunch 1",
      "priceList": [
        {
          "price": 6.59,
          "currency": "DH"
        },
        {
          "price": 5.19,
          "currency": "YN"
        }
      ],
      "productList": [
        {
          "productCode": "bKSZqaYa"
        },
        {
          "productCode": "MM3FbWRu"
        }
      ],
      "merchantCode": "jjijuhikl",
      "qte": 2,
      "isCombo": true
    }
  ];

var productList = currentSale
    .filter(i => i.isCombo === false)
    .map(x => {
        return {
            code: x.code,
            quantity: x.qte,
            unitPrice: x.unitPrice  // which price do you want?
        }
    });

var comboList = currentSale
    .filter(i => i.isCombo === true)
    .map(x => {
        return {
            code: x.code,
            quantity: x.qte,
            unitPrice: x.unitPrice  // which price do you want?
        }
    });

console.log('productList', productList);
console.log('comboList', comboList);
```

Comment: thank you, I choose price from another variable like this {unitPrice: x.priceList[transactionCurrency === 'DH' ? 1 : 0].price} it works good

Answer (score 1):

you can use `map` function and do something like that:

```
comboList = comboList.map(({ code, unitPrice, qte }) => {
  return {
    code,
    unitPrice,
    quantity: qte
  };
});
```